# Perfect Scrollbar not working in Angular

Tags: angular, perfect-scrollbar

I'm trying to add a styled scrollbar to my Angular application using the following library:
https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-perfect-scrollbar

I followed the documentation in that link and added the imports to my app.module.ts file, but I keep getting errors when trying to use it.

I also tried importing PerfectScrollbarModule and PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface to the component I'm using it in, but still no luck.

I tried all of the following HTML, but they resulted in the corresponding error messages. What am I missing? By the way, I'm on the most recent version of Angular.

```
<perfect-scrollbar class="container" [config]="config">
  <div class="content">Scrollable content</div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

> Can't bind to 'config' since it isn't a known property of
>   'perfect-scrollbar'.

```
<perfect-scrollbar class="container">
  <div class="content">Scrollable content</div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

> 'perfect-scrollbar' is not a known element:

```
<div [perfect-scrollbar]="config">
    ...
</div
```

> Can't bind to 'perfect-scrollbar' since it isn't a known property of
>   'div'

UPDATE:

I added `ngx-perfect-scrollbar': 'npm:ngx-perfect-scrollbar'` to the map object is my systemjs file and the following to the packages object:

```
'ngx-perfect-scrollbar': {
    main: 'bundles/ngx-perfect-scrollbar.umd.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
```

Here are the relevant parts of my **app.module.ts** file:

```
import { PerfectScrollbarModule }          from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';

export const PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true
};

@NgModule({ 
    imports: [        
        ...
        PerfectScrollbarModule.forRoot(PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG)
    ],
    ...
})
```

Comment: Did you get the solution to this issue? if yes, please share.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else looking for an answer to this, the problem is because the directive attribute has been changed from `[perfect-scrollbar]` to `[perfectScrollbar]`.

Comment: This was cause of my problem

Answer (score 5):

If the component where you want to use the perfect scrollbar depends on another module than `app.module` (for instance `header.module`...), you should also import `PerfectScrollbarModule` in this submodule. You can do it the exact same way you did in your `app.module`.

Comment: when importing perfect-scrollbar in submodule getting this error => ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Subject_1.Subject is not a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, did you install it correctly? I mean did you run this command? `npm install ngx-perfect-scrollbar --save-dev`, If no, then you should do it first to be able to play with that library.

Comment: Yup, I installed it succesfully

Comment: @Brett Can you find it in "package.json" file?

Comment: Yup, it says "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^4.0.0",

Comment: I edited my post to show the code I added to my systemjs file

Comment: Why would you do that, you only have to do the following: 
1- install it using the above command, then import it in the "app.module.ts" file. Can you show me your app.module.ts file?

Comment: Without adding anything to systemjs, i got the following error: GET http://localhost:3000/ngx-perfect-scrollbar 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I updated my post to show the relevant parts of my app.module.ts file. Do you need to see the entire thing?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me **npm install ngx-perfect-scrollbar --save-dev**

Comment: Duplicate answer